# Mips translating problems

Tags: mips, pseudocode

I am having trouble translating this pseudo code to mips assembly i have added the registers i am using to help understand what is going on

```
# if (n == 1)
#   return 1
# else if (n == 2)
#   return 6
# else
#   return 2*hex(n-1) - hex(n-2) + 4

# (hex) Registers:
# $a0 - n, the argument
# $v0 - the result the n-th Hexamorphic number
# $t0 - holds hex(n-2)
# $t1 - holds constants 1
# $t2 - holds constant 2
```

here is where i am at in my code i feel confident about hex: and elseif: but the else: is where the problem starts

```
hex:    bne $a0,$t1,elseif #if n==1
        li $t1,1
        li $t2,2
        li $v0,1 
        jr $ra         #retu

elseif: bne $a0, $t2,else
        li $v0,6
        jr $ra

else:   addi $sp,$sp,-12
    sw $ra,$ra 0($sp)
    addi $t3,$a0,-1
    sll $t3, $t2,1
    sw $a0,$a0,4($sp)
    sw $t3,8($sp)
    lw $ra
    lw $a0
    addi $t3,4
    sub $t4,$t3,$t0
    lw $t4
    sw $v0,$t4
    lw $ra
    lw $a0
    j $ra
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some instructions wrong (`sw`, `lw`, `addi` and `j`). The definitions of these intstructions can be found in the [MIPS32 instruction set quick reference](https://www.mips.com/media/files/MD00565-2B-MIPS32-QRC-01.01.pdf).

You're on the right track in the else block. What you want to do is save all the values (on the stack) that you want to be preserved throughout your recursive calls. `jal` to hex (n - 1), save it on the stack and `jal` to hex again (n - 2). Then load up all values, do the calculations on them and `jr ra`. Do not forget to restore $sp before returning. When using `jal`, remember the branch delay:

```
jal hex
The instruction here will be run "together" with jal, before taking the branch.
ra will point here
```

The `jr $ra` in elseif will run `addi $sp,$sp,-12` due to branch delay. This is not good.